# Need to allow standard users to run sc stop/sc start commands for e1iexpress

Tags: drivers, permissions, batch, active-directory

A persistent problem we have is that on our computers, our internet drivers crash when laptops move from place to place. In theory, we could solve this by giving the users a script to restart the driver with sc stop and sc start; in practice, we can't give our users admin permissions, and any method involving /SaveCred would be very time-intensive, as we have quite a few computers here. (Unless we can use SaveCred once on a server and let everyone just access that batch file? I don't know if that works.)

We're running Win10 with an Active Directory backend. Any help would be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services (including drivers) have a *security descriptor*, in other words an ACL, similar to files and folders. This describes which users can use what controls (start, stop, pause, etc.)

You can retrieve the raw security descriptor via `sc sdshow <svcname>`, update it with new access rights, then use `sc sdset ...` to store it back. See [this ServerFault thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/187302/how-do-i-grant-start-stop-restart-permissions-on-a-service-to-an-arbitrary-user) for instructions on doing so manually.

You can *probably* set service permissions via Group Policy. Unfortunately the policy editor seems to list only built-in Windows services (with no ability to enter a custom name), although technically there's no reason it shouldn't be able to edit them.

Third-party programs also exist to edit service ACLs graphically. Personally I would use "Process Hacker" for this to build the desired SD on one computer, then grab it via `sc sdshow` and distribute that. There's also SubInACL, possibly PowerShell *Set-Acl*.

See also:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/187302/how-do-i-grant-start-stop-restart-permissions-on-a-service-to-an-arbitrary-user
- https://blogs.msmvps.com/erikr/2007/09/26/set-permissions-on-a-specific-service-windows/

Comment: In theory, I should be able to use the domain controller to throw the sc sdset command into a startup script, and give Authenticated Users the right to start/stop those commands with RP/WP. That worked, but then when I tried to actually stop the service, the error shifted from "Access Denied" to 

[SC] ControlService FAILED 1052:

The requested control is not valid for this service.

Which is... _great_. So this may have been a waste of time. But thanks a lot for the answer! :)